# Mist / Ethereum Wallet question

Tags: blockchain, wallets, mist

I bought a very small amount of ETH on coinbase just to try it, and I wanted to create my own wallet to get it out.

However, I've been trying to get Mist working for 3 days and it is always stuck on some step: not connecting to peers, the blocks stuck without downloading, chain structures increasing faster than my computer can download them, and crashing my admittedly modest Intel i5 @ 2.80 GHz/ 6 gb RAM computer.

I'm aware I can just launch the application and get an account, but shouldn't it work all the way? Does it matter that I can never sync completely?

I can also just use myetherwallet but I really wanted the official recommended desktop app to work. I don't want to disparage ether and I'm really glad that my ETH revaluates every day or almost every hour, but how do you expect widespread acceptance if the official app appears not to work?

I hope this post doesn't get flagged as "pointless", and that someone can really explain if I'm doing or understanding something wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Mist and Geth. The reason is that bottleneck is your HDD (hard disk drive). To run Mist or Geth normally you should have SSD (solid state drive) on your computer. 
So i would recommend to install Parity desktop wallet. It runs fine on computer with HDD.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is related to a system's drive.  I've a new system, high spec system, with SSD and have the same issue.

Comment: It may take really long time to sync with Mist or Geth. Both downloading whole blockchain. I used Parity instead and it synced much more fast. If you want just a wallet there's no sense to download whole ethereum blockchain.

Comment: I think it's just buggy.  I've a 1Gb/1Gb fiber line, and all but the last few blocks will download then the chainstructure starts racing.  I've seen this happen on three fairly well spec'd machines now.  I've found no great solutions.  The one that has worked for me is to try, try again.  That is close the app when it appears to be hung and re-open.  Wait on the splash screen and watch for it to succeed or start racing again.  Then try again, and again.  Eventually it gets past it.  Three times now, and once took about an hour, the other times, day or so.  I prefer a full node myself for dev.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware regarding Mist / Etherwallet issues (if official wallet doesn't work, I'd suggest to ask support). But if you just want to get control over your money you can use [Metamask](http://metamask.io).

I assume you have private / public keys access (you have already bought some crypto). Just:

1. install [Metamask](http://metamask.io);
2. import Account with private key - [How to import your MyEtherWallet account into MetaMask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grsBwSDSeuQ);
3. you have full control of your funds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mist the official Wallet software for ethereum then you should know that after the first install Mist will allow you to create a new wallet, import a older one and so on.
But after that, that is on your Next Start of Mist, the software by default will connect your local node and you are running a Ethereum Node.
So the Splashscreen will show up sayining: "Ethereum node connected"
That means the software is syncing the entire network and that can take up to 7 days ...
Yes, it can take up to that time always on to sync ... so be patient.
I do not know a way to start the GUI without by default syncing.

Answer (score 0):

When you start Mist, it tries to connect to locally running Ethereum node, and, if there is no such node, it starts one.

While Mist itself is not to heavy, Ethereum node may consume lots of resources.  You may try to run local node yourself in "light" mode like this:

```
geth --syncmode light
```

and, once it started, run Mist.  Light mode is way faster then default sync mode.

Comment: [Just to be clear to anyone reading this, Mist (and Ethereum Wallet) has been deprecated since March 2019.]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Metamask because as of March 2019 Mist(Ethereum wallet) has been deprecated. So it is natural that while using it you might run into problems.

Metamask can be added as an extension in your browser and you can use Remix along with it.

Using Metamask you can connect to your local or public blockchain. And use it to interact with the smart contracts deployed.

New here! Any corrections and suggestions are welcome.